# Log all traffic on https with iptables rules

Tags: linux, https, router, iptables

I am interested in logging all traffic that comes over port 443 for trouble-shooting some connection handling / blocking that we are working on.  What is the best way (even if it is way overkill at first in completeness) to log all https / port 443 traffic?

Oh ... and this would be logging at a gateway/router ... so it will be logging all of the traffic as it comes in from the LAN side.  In this instance, not concerned about the WAN side - just want to log all **outgoing** traffic from the LAN side.  I know I won't see the content of it - I just want to see the connections (source IP and dest IP) as they come thru the iptables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this.

iptables -I INPUT -i LAN_Interface  -s 0.0.0.0/0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j LOG

You will see logs in /var/log/messages